# how to compile objective-c source code with clang in mingw64-x86 via apple libobjc.dll?

Tags: objective-c, windows, gcc, runtime, clang

i have a problem when compile objective-c source code on windows platform.
of course compile objective-c source code on windows platform , we usually using gnustep environment(gcc objecitve-c compiler . gnustep libojc dynamic library . gnustep foundation framework ... and so on).

but i want a clean environment try compiler objective-c , and use a different libobjc library.

since mac os x 10.6 . apple move macosx system to x86 platform(no ppc support any more) , AND REWRITE system application by cocoa tech.include iTunes.

and iTunes have windows version.

by searching system folders after install iTunes.i found any support dll file in:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Apple Application Support`

by the way , my system is windows 7 x86_64.

i found it has:

```
ApplePushService.dll
AppleVersions.dll
APSDaemon_main.dll
ASL.dll
AVFoundationCF.dll
CFNetwork.dll
CoreAudioToolbox.dll
CoreFoundation.dll
CoreGraphics.dll
CoreMedia.dll
CoreText.dll
CoreVideo.dll
Foundation.dll
icudt46.dll
icuin40.dll
icuuc40.dll
JavaScriptCore.dll
libcache.dll
libdispatch.dll
libicuin.dll
libicuuc.dll
libtidy.dll
libxml2.dll
libxslt.dll
MediaToolbox.dll
objc.dll
pthreadVC2.dll
QTMovieWin.dll
QuartzCore.dll
SQLite3.dll
VideoToolbox.dll
WebKit.dll
WebKitQuartzCoreAdditions.dll
YSCrashDump.dll
YSUtilities.dll
zlib1.dll
```

look like , apple implement these low level framework to windows platform.

```
CFNetwork.framework -> CFNetwork.dll 

CoreGraphics.framework -> CoreGraphics.dll

Foundation.framework -> Foundation.dll

libobjc.a.dylib -> objc.dll

WebKit.framework -> WebKit.dll
```

so , i think using apple's libobjc release version is better(iTunes is running well).the others library file is useful too.

i want build a learnning environment for objective-c beginner people(my class mates and i).

so i copy objc.dll and rename it to libobjc.dll

using mingw tool "pexports" export libobjc.dll 's def to libobjc.def then using visual studio command tool "lib.exe" convert .def file to libobjc.lib.

then i download

- mingw64's x86(32 bit) compilers dng precompiled package.
- mingw64's clang+llvm(32 bit) compilers dng precompiled package.
- mingw64's msys environment precompiled package.

install these 3 package to system.
then copy libobjc.dll,libobjc.lib to /lib (on windows platform , .a and .lib using same bin format).

then i wrote a sample objective-c source code.code is here:
file:test.m

```
#import <stdio.h>

@interface Foo {
    int count;
}

+ (void)fooWithBar;

@end

@implementation Foo

+ (void)fooWithBar {
    printf("abc");
}

@end


int main(){
    [Foo fooWithBar];
    return 0;
}
```

simply compile it:

`clang test.m`

error happen, then using -v options show detail:

```
clang version 3.1 (branches/release_31)
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Thread model: posix
 "c:/mingw64w32/bin/clang.exe" -cc1 -triple i686-w64-mingw32 -S -disable-free -main-file-name test.m -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu pentium4 -target-linker-version 2.20.51.0.2 -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -resource-dir "c:/mingw64w32/bin\\..\\lib\\clang\\3.1" -fmodule-cache-path "C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp\\clang-module-cache" -fno-dwarf-directory-asm -fdebug-compilation-dir C:/MINGW64-X86-MSYS-20111123/home/Joe -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -mstackrealign -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fgnu-runtime -fobjc-runtime-has-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-fragile-abi -fobjc-exceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -o C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-709512.s -x objective-c test.m
clang -cc1 version 3.1 based upon LLVM 3.1 default target i686-w64-mingw32
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/clang/3.1/../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/clang/3.1/include
 c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/clang/3.1/../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include
 c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/clang/3.1/../../../include
End of search list.
 "c:/mingw64w32/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe" -v -c -o C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-709513.o -x assembler C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-709512.s
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:/mingw64w32/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: /home/drangon/work/mingw-w64-dgn_32/source/gcc/configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++ --with-gmp=/home/drangon/work/mingw-w64-dgn_32/build/for_target --enable-twoprocess --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-win32-registry --prefix=/home/drangon/work/mingw-w64-dgn_32/target --with-sysroot=/home/drangon/work/mingw-w64-dgn_32/target
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.7.2 20120823 (prerelease) (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-o' 'C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-709513.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-709513.o C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-709512.s
GNU assembler version 2.23.51 (i686-w64-mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.23.51.20120823
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw64w32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/;c:/mingw64w32/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/;c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../lib/;c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-o' 'C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-709513.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 "c:/mingw64w32/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe" -v -o a.out C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-709513.o
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:/mingw64w32/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw64w32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: /home/drangon/work/mingw-w64-dgn_32/source/gcc/configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++ --with-gmp=/home/drangon/work/mingw-w64-dgn_32/build/for_target --enable-twoprocess --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-win32-registry --prefix=/home/drangon/work/mingw-w64-dgn_32/target --with-sysroot=/home/drangon/work/mingw-w64-dgn_32/target
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.7.2 20120823 (prerelease) (GCC) 
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw64w32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/;c:/mingw64w32/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/;c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../lib/;c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'a.out' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 c:/mingw64w32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/collect2.exe --sysroot=/home/drangon/work/mingw-w64-dgn_32/target -m i386pe -Bdynamic -o a.out c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/crtbegin.o -Lc:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2 -Lc:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -Lc:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../lib -Lc:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib -Lc:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../.. C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-709513.o -lmingw32 -lgcc_eh -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_eh -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/crtend.o
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-709513.o:fake:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `objc_lookup_class'
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-709513.o:fake:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `objc_msg_lookup'
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-709513.o:fake:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `__objc_exec_class'
c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-709513.o: bad reloc address 0x14 in section `.data'
c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
clang: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

by google searching , i found objc_lookup_class is a method defined in gnustep's libobjc library.and in apple's libojbc.dll 's .def file:"libojbc.def" , i found another method named "objc_lookUpClass".
google searching again.so,
apple's libojbc are different with gnustep's libobjc.
apple's libojbc using NextStep library interface.gnustep made a different one.

`man gcc`

gcc have two options about this.

`-fgnu-runtime` . that's gcc's default options,using gnu style runtime.
`-fnext-runtime` , this using nextstep(now it's apple) style running.

so i pass nextstep style option to clang(or gcc?).
`clang -fnext-runtime`

compile .o to .s with no error.seem like ld.exe finds all method it need from apple's libobjc library file.but another error happen,with -v options,here are detail:

```
clang version 3.1 (branches/release_31)
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Thread model: posix
 "c:/mingw64w32/bin/clang.exe" -cc1 -triple i686-w64-mingw32 -S -disable-free -main-file-name test.m -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu pentium4 -target-linker-version 2.20.51.0.2 -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -resource-dir "c:/mingw64w32/bin\\..\\lib\\clang\\3.1" -fmodule-cache-path "C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp\\clang-module-cache" -fno-dwarf-directory-asm -fdebug-compilation-dir C:/MINGW64-X86-MSYS-20111123/home/Joe -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -mstackrealign -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fobjc-fragile-abi -fobjc-exceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -o C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s -x objective-c test.m
clang -cc1 version 3.1 based upon LLVM 3.1 default target i686-w64-mingw32
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/clang/3.1/../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/clang/3.1/include
 c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/clang/3.1/../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include
 c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/clang/3.1/../../../include
End of search list.
 "c:/mingw64w32/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe" -fnext-runtime -v -c -o C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467379.o -x assembler C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:/mingw64w32/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: /home/drangon/work/mingw-w64-dgn_32/source/gcc/configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++ --with-gmp=/home/drangon/work/mingw-w64-dgn_32/build/for_target --enable-twoprocess --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-win32-registry --prefix=/home/drangon/work/mingw-w64-dgn_32/target --with-sysroot=/home/drangon/work/mingw-w64-dgn_32/target
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.7.2 20120823 (prerelease) (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-fnext-runtime' '-v' '-c' '-o' 'C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467379.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 c:/mingw64w32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467379.o C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s
GNU assembler version 2.23.51 (i686-w64-mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.23.51.20120823
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s: Assembler messages:
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:4: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.lazy_reference'
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:57: Error: bad or irreducible absolute expression
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:57: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:67: Error: bad or irreducible absolute expression
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:67: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:76: Error: bad or irreducible absolute expression
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:76: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:92: Error: bad or irreducible absolute expression
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:92: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:99: Error: bad or irreducible absolute expression
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:99: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:107: Error: bad or irreducible absolute expression
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:107: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:123: Error: bad or irreducible absolute expression
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:123: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:128: Error: bad or irreducible absolute expression
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:128: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:133: Error: bad or irreducible absolute expression
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:133: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:137: Error: bad or irreducible absolute expression
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:137: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:146: Error: bad or irreducible absolute expression
C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Temp/test-467378.s:146: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
clang: error: assembler (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

i don't know Assembler language.but seem like Assembler app couldn't understand this .s file.
so i using -S option to keep .s files.one is clang with -fgnu-runtime . other is clang with -fnext-runtime.

//test.s ,clang with -fgnu-runtime option

```
    .def     __c_Foo__fooWithBar;
    .scl    3;
    .type    32;
    .endef
    .text
    .align    16, 0x90
__c_Foo__fooWithBar:
    pushl    %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    movl    8(%ebp), %ecx
    leal    L_.str, %edx
    movl    %ecx, -4(%ebp)
    movl    %eax, -8(%ebp)
    movl    %edx, (%esp)
    calll    _printf
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    addl    $16, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret

    .def     _main;
    .scl    2;
    .type    32;
    .endef
    .globl    _main
    .align    16, 0x90
_main:
    pushl    %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl    %esi
    subl    $20, %esp
    calll    ___main
    leal    L_.class_name, %eax
    movl    $0, -8(%ebp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    calll    _objc_lookup_class
    leal    _.objc_selector_list, %ecx
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    movl    %ecx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    calll    _objc_msg_lookup
    movl    $0, %ecx
    leal    _.objc_selector_list, %edx
    movl    -12(%ebp), %esi
    movl    %esi, (%esp)
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %ecx, -16(%ebp)
    calll    *%eax
    movl    -16(%ebp), %eax
    addl    $20, %esp
    popl    %esi
    popl    %ebp
    ret

    .def     _.objc_load_function;
    .scl    3;
    .type    32;
    .endef
    .align    16, 0x90
_.objc_load_function:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl    %ebp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset %ebp, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %ebp
    pushl    %eax
    leal    ___unnamed_1, %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    calll    ___objc_exec_class
    addl    $4, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
    .cfi_endproc

    .data
L_.str:
    .asciz     "abc"

    .globl    ___objc_class_name_Foo
    .align    4
___objc_class_name_Foo:
    .long    0

L___unnamed_2:
    .asciz     "count"

L___unnamed_3:
    .asciz     "i"

    .globl    ___objc_ivar_offset_value_Foo.count
    .align    4
___objc_ivar_offset_value_Foo.count:
    .long    0

    .align    4
_.ivar.offsets:
    .long    ___objc_ivar_offset_value_Foo.count

    .lcomm    _.objc_property_list,8,8
L___unnamed_4:
    .asciz     "v8@0:4"

L___unnamed_5:
    .asciz     "fooWithBar"

    .align    16
_.objc_method_list:
    .long    0
    .long    1
    .long    L___unnamed_5
    .long    L___unnamed_4
    .long    __c_Foo__fooWithBar

    .align    8
_.objc_ivar_list:
    .long    1
    .long    L___unnamed_2
    .long    L___unnamed_3
    .long    0

    .globl    ___objc_ivar_offset_Foo.count
    .align    4
___objc_ivar_offset_Foo.count:
    .long    _.objc_ivar_list+12

L_.class_name:
    .asciz     "Foo"

    .globl    __OBJC_METACLASS_Foo
    .align    16
__OBJC_METACLASS_Foo:
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .long    L_.class_name
    .long    0
    .long    18
    .long    72
    .long    0
    .long    _.objc_method_list
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .long    1
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .long    0

    .lcomm    _.objc_protocol_list,8,8
    .globl    __OBJC_CLASS_Foo
    .align    16
__OBJC_CLASS_Foo:
    .long    __OBJC_METACLASS_Foo
    .long    0
    .long    L_.class_name
    .long    0
    .long    17
    .long    4
    .long    _.objc_ivar_list
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .long    _.objc_protocol_list
    .long    0
    .long    1
    .long    _.ivar.offsets
    .long    _.objc_property_list
    .long    1
    .long    1

    .section    .rdata$__objc_class_ref_Foo,"r"
    .linkonce discard
    .globl    ___objc_class_ref_Foo
    .align    4
___objc_class_ref_Foo:
    .long    ___objc_class_name_Foo

    .data
L___unnamed_6:
    .asciz     "AnotherHack"

L___unnamed_7:
    .asciz     "__ObjC_Protocol_Holder_Ugly_Hack"

    .lcomm    _.objc_protocol_list1,8,8
    .align    16
___unnamed_8:
    .long    L___unnamed_6
    .long    L___unnamed_7
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .long    _.objc_protocol_list1

    .section    .rdata$.objc_sel_namefooWithBar,"r"
    .linkonce discard
    .globl    _.objc_sel_namefooWithBar
_.objc_sel_namefooWithBar:
    .asciz     "fooWithBar"

    .data
    .align    8
_.objc_selector_list:
    .long    _.objc_sel_namefooWithBar
    .long    L___unnamed_4
    .zero    8

    .align    16
___unnamed_9:
    .long    1
    .long    _.objc_selector_list
    .short    1
    .short    1
    .long    __OBJC_CLASS_Foo
    .long    ___unnamed_8
    .long    0
    .long    0

L_.objc_source_file_name:
    .asciz     "./test.m"

    .align    8
___unnamed_1:
    .long    8
    .long    16
    .long    L_.objc_source_file_name
    .long    ___unnamed_9

    .section    .ctors,"w"
    .align    4
    .long    _.objc_load_function
```

//test.s ,clang with -fnext-runtime option

```
    .objc_class_name_Foo=0
    .globl .objc_class_name_Foo
    .lazy_reference .objc_class_name_Foo


    .def     _2B__5B_Foo_20_fooWithBar_5D_;
    .scl    3;
    .type    32;
    .endef
    .text
    .align    16, 0x90
_2B__5B_Foo_20_fooWithBar_5D_:
    pushl    %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    movl    8(%ebp), %ecx
    leal    L_.str, %edx
    movl    %ecx, -4(%ebp)
    movl    %eax, -8(%ebp)
    movl    %edx, (%esp)
    calll    _printf
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    addl    $16, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret

    .def     _main;
    .scl    2;
    .type    32;
    .endef
    .globl    _main
    .align    16, 0x90
_main:
    pushl    %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $16, %esp
    calll    ___main
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    $0, -4(%ebp)
    movl    L_OBJC_CLASS_REFERENCES_, %ecx
    movl    L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_, %edx
    movl    %ecx, (%esp)
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, -8(%ebp)
    calll    _objc_msgSend
    movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    $16, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret

    .data
L_.str:
    .asciz     "abc"

    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals,"w"
L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_:
    .asciz     "fooWithBar"

L_OBJC_METH_VAR_TYPE_:
    .asciz     "v8@0:4"

L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_:
    .asciz     "Foo"

    .section    __OBJC,__cls_meth,regular,no_dead_strip,"w"
    .align    4
L_OBJC_CLASS_METHODS_Foo:
    .long    0
    .long    1
    .long    L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_
    .long    L_OBJC_METH_VAR_TYPE_
    .long    _2B__5B_Foo_20_fooWithBar_5D_

    .section    __OBJC,__meta_class,regular,no_dead_strip,"w"
    .align    4
L_OBJC_METACLASS_Foo:
    .long    L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_
    .long    0
    .long    L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_
    .long    0
    .long    2
    .long    48
    .long    0
    .long    L_OBJC_CLASS_METHODS_Foo
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .long    0

    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals,"w"
L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_1:
    .asciz     "count"

L_OBJC_METH_VAR_TYPE_2:
    .asciz     "i"

    .section    __OBJC,__instance_vars,regular,no_dead_strip,"w"
    .align    4
L_OBJC_INSTANCE_VARIABLES_Foo:
    .long    1
    .long    L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_1
    .long    L_OBJC_METH_VAR_TYPE_2
    .long    0

    .section    __OBJC,__class,regular,no_dead_strip,"w"
    .align    4
L_OBJC_CLASS_Foo:
    .long    L_OBJC_METACLASS_Foo
    .long    0
    .long    L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_
    .long    0
    .long    1
    .long    4
    .long    L_OBJC_INSTANCE_VARIABLES_Foo
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .long    0

    .section    __OBJC,__cls_refs,literal_pointers,no_dead_strip,"w"
    .align    4
L_OBJC_CLASS_REFERENCES_:
    .long    L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_

    .section    __OBJC,__message_refs,literal_pointers,no_dead_strip,"w"
    .align    4
L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_:
    .long    L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_

    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals,"w"
L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_3:
    .zero    1

    .section    __OBJC,__symbols,regular,no_dead_strip,"w"
    .align    4
L_OBJC_SYMBOLS:
    .long    0
    .long    0
    .short    1
    .short    0
    .long    L_OBJC_CLASS_Foo

    .section    __OBJC,__module_info,regular,no_dead_strip,"w"
    .align    4
L_OBJC_MODULES:
    .long    7
    .long    16
    .long    L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_3
    .long    L_OBJC_SYMBOLS
```

i believe the key issues is from the .s file create way.

anyone can help me fix this problem?
althrough using these .dll file could not create application for business.

but by using these .dll , we could build a greate cocoa learnning environment on window platform. all framework's windows version is more stable and useful than gnustep.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all this is in violation of the iTunes EULA, so whether commercial or not you're not supposed to do it.

Second problem is that -fnext-runtime in clang/gcc only functions on Darwin, it is missing assorted bits and pieces for Windows and other operating systems. I'd (educated) guess and assume -fgnu-runtime is useless for linking against Apple's own frameworks.

As you can see -fnext-runtime is emitting Darwin specific assembler command, e.g. .lazy_reference, on Windows, not a great start.

This has been the situation with -fnext-runtime in gcc and now clang for quite a long time, no one maintains -fnext-runtime in the mainlines for non-Darwin systems.

My rough understanding is that Apple actually does not use clang directly on Windows, they rewrite the Objective-C into C and use Visual Studio to compile for Windows.

You can either start doing some serious hacking on clang, or don't bother.

Comment: But I also think using visual studio to compile objective-c application is not good job for apple.using llvm-gcc's apple custom version could make thing better. Thank you for tell me that .s file is Darwin assembler code.i will check gcc source code. Thank you very much.

Comment: yea, clang support for Windows is still kind of rough, Apple doesn't appear to be doing any work there, and unfortunately few others are as well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do exactly the same as you have recently, and I found similar results. The core (technical, not legal) issue is that `-fnext-runtime` isn't supported on Windows and probably won't ever be supported. I will get to `-fgnu-runtime` in a moment.

No matter how basic an Objective-C program you write on Windows you will always end up with unresolved references. Looking inside the `.dll` files you will find that they simply do not contain some of the core methods required to link an Objective-C program compiled with Clang on Windows. (If memory serves I was able to compile a program that had only 2 unresolved references as a minimum).

So on the basis that `-fnext-runtime` is not supported, you can try `-fgnu-runtime` with GCC. Of course, you lose compatibility with all Apple's libraries, but you *do* get working Objective-C programs on Windows. GCC recently upgraded their Objective-C runtime to work almost identically to Apple's Objective-C runtime so compatibility is now much less of an issue.

Again, you don't get Apple's libraries, you'd have to write them yourself (any takers?) but the runtime works in the same way. It takes a bit of working to [make your own `NSObject`](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-01-25-lets-build-nsobject.html) (looking at [Apple's implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/NSObject.mm) helps though) and [Constant String @"..." object](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constant-string-objects.html) but once you have them, you can build up your own Windows-compatible Objective-C framework. From experience I can tell you that it is definitely possible.